# Attask API InvalidTimelineReferenceException thrown

Tags: attask

When using the Attask API to move a subtask from one "parent" task to another, I receive the following exception within the http response:

{"error":{"class":"com.attask.common.InvalidTimelineReferenceException","message":"Invalid Timeline. Task number TASK53b1b1b4016ecc0540791164a0fa27d0 was not found in the current timeline.","title":null,"msgKey":"exception.attask","attributes":[""],"code":0}}

I've seen no documentation regarding this object class or error.

What does this message mean, and how can it be overcome?

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to attach a task to another task but both tasks are in a different project. I would make sure both tasks are in the same project, if they are not move one into the others project first and then retry your call. Hope that helps.